# How to remove a record from a DbContext where there is list within a list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a DbContext that has a table Gizmos

```
public Gizmo
{
   public Guid Id {get;set;}
   public ICollection<Widget> Widgets {get;set;} = new List<Widget>();
}
```

So a Gizmo can have a list of Widgets.

I want to delete 1 widget from the Gizmo.

I cannot directly access Widget from the context.  It has to be done through the Gizmo.

I want to do something similar to:

```
_context.Gizmos.SelectMany(x => x.Widgets).Remove(x => x.Id == myId);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: What do you mean by *I cannot directly access Widget from the context*?

Comment: If it was it's own table I could do _context.Widget.Remove(x => x.Id == myId)

Comment: What is Widget? Has it a such Remove() method?

Comment: No it does not have that method

Widget is just a simple object with an Id and Name in this case

Comment: Why not add a `DbSet<Widget>` property to the `DbContext` type? Then you could delete it directly instead of using a navigation property. My question is "I cannot directly access Widget from the context. It has to be done through the Gizmo." ← Why is that a requirement?

Comment: You need to find the Gizmo which has the Widget you need to remove. Then find the widget, then remove it using `_context.Set<Widget>().Remove(yourWidget);`

Comment: Mat that is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Linq as what you want because queries don't allow to manipulate original source since they are collection results containing filtered and transformed references.

**You can simply achieve your goal without Linq**

```
foreach ( var gizmo in _context.Gizmos )
  foreach (var widget in gizmo.Widgets.ToList() )
    if ( widget.Id == myId )
      gizmo.Widgets.Remove(widget);
```

The ToList() is to avoid index conflict when removing.

**Fastest alternative**

```
for ( int indexGizmo = 0; indexGizmo < _context.Gizmos.Count(); indexGizmo++ )
{
  var gizmo = _context.Gizmos[indexGizmo];
  for ( int indexWidget = gizmo.Widgets.Count() - 1; indexWidget >= 0; indexWidget-- )
  {
    var widget = gizmo.Widgets[indexWidget];
    if ( widget.Id == myId )
      gizmo.Widgets.Remove(widget);
  }
}
```

**Using Linq and a loop on the query to remove items**

```
var query = from gizmo in _context.Gizmos
            from widget in gizmo.Widgets
            where widget.Id == myId
            select new { gizmo, widget };

foreach ( var result in query )
  result.gizmo.Widgets.Remove(result.widget);
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot do a Query (the Select) and a NonQuery( the Remove) at the same time. You first have to download it, and manifest it in memory, this is what "ToList()" does. Than you can Remove it. the Where-Clause you can append to the Select, so you download only the items you want to remove.

```
var list = _context.Gizmos.SelectMany(x => x.Widgets).Where(x => x.Id == myId).ToList();
_context.Widgets.RemoveRange(list);
_context.SaveChanges();
enter code here
```

But usually, if you have an ID of widget, you go to the DbSet of Widget and delete it there.
You don't need to take care of deleting it from Gizmos. EF and SQL will take care of that.

If your ID is unique and you expect only one Item, you can also just use

```
SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == myId)
```

instead of Where and ToList()

And if ID is the primary key, you can just use

```
var widget = context.Widgets.Find(myID);
context.Widgets.Remove(widget);
context.SaveChanges();
```

As further optimization you can read about "Delete without Fetch" to get around the requirement to download first, before you can delete something.

That would be something like

```
 var widget = new Widget { ID = myID };
 context.Widgets.Attach(widget);
 context.Entry(width).State = EntityState.Deleted;
 context.SaveChanges();
```